# SwiftUI: avoid recreating/rerendering view in TabView with MKMapView+UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, mapkit, swiftui

I have a TabView with three tabs, one of which contains a map view that's implemented like this:

```swift
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion
    let animatedRegion: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: animatedRegion)
        return mapView
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView

        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
        }
    }
}
```

The tab view is implemented like this:

```swift
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    MapView(/* params */)
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
            Text("map")
        }.tag(1)
    Text("Screen #2")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
            Text("2")
        }.tag(2)
    Text("Screen #3")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
            Text("3")
        }.tag(3)
}
```

The problem is that the makeUIView(:context) method is executed every time I switch back to the map tab from one of the other two tabs. It appears that the underlying MKMapView instance is deallocated when I switch to another tab, then it's recreated when I switch back. In UIKit it doesn't rerender the whole view like that. Am I doing something wrong, or is there anything I can do to make sure that the underlying MKMapView instance is retained when I switch back so that it doesn't have to recreate it every single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store instance of `MKMapView` for each tab and destroy before you leaving the view because SwiftUI will destroy MapView when it need to render for example the binding vars have changed.

```swift
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    static private var mapViews = [Int: MKMapView]()

    let region: MKCoordinateRegion
    let animatedRegion: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        guard MapView.mapViews[currentTab] != nil else { return MapView.mapViews[currentTab]! }

        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: animatedRegion)

        MapView.mapViews[currentTab] = mapView

        return mapView
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView

        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I implemented a slightly modified version of your code that suits my needs and it works great. https://pastebin.com/pyYStaHn

Comment: I would move `mapView.setRegion(region, animated: animatedRegion)` to `updateUIView` because if `region` changes then setRegion won't run.

Comment: i never experienced this with MapView. but the WebView as UIRepresentable behaves this way. Recreates all tabs in the TabView

Answer (score -4):

use EnvironmentObject. always update it and pass it in TabView {MapView(coordinates: Object.coordinates)}